# How to make my existing R codes output a specific count of odd and even numbers?

Tags: r, random

I have the following codes running in `R`. It basically outputs 6 `random` numbers based on my choice of the frequency of numbers from each `list`.

```
foo <- list(
  c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
  c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
  c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30), 
  c(31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40) 
)

names(foo) <- c(3, 2, 1, 0)

list2<- unlist(sapply(seq_along(foo), function(x) sample(foo[[x]], names(foo[x]))))

sort(list2)
```

So, above codes will output 6 `random` numbers (3 from 1st list, 2 from 2nd list, 1 from 3rd list and none from 4th list).

I want to also be able to add to these codes the choice of selecting the number of `odd` numbers and `even` numbers in the final output.

Let's say I want to keep the existing codes but I want the output to be a mix of 4 `even` numbers and 2 `odd` numbers.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many options for you, but the easiest is to use infinite loop. But, before the loop you need 2 more functions to count the odds:

```
is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 != 0

countOdds<-function(dt){ sum(sapply(dt, is.odd)) }
```

and then the loop is:

```
while(T){
  list2<- unlist(sapply(seq_along(foo), function(x) sample(foo[[x]], names(foo[x]))))
  if(countOdds(list2)==2)
    break
}
```

Generally, it ***continuously*** produces different answers, but it only stops, if it finds 2 odds and 4 evens.

---

**The whole code together is:**

```
foo <- list(
  c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
  c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
  c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30), 
  c(31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40) 
)

names(foo) <- c(3, 2, 1, 0)


is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 != 0

countOdds<-function(dt){ sum(sapply(dt, is.odd)) }



while(T){
  list2<- unlist(sapply(seq_along(foo), function(x) sample(foo[[x]], names(foo[x]))))
  if(countOdds(list2)==2)
    break
}

sort(list2)
```

and the result is:

## 4  6  7 11 12 30

## 6  9 10 16 17 24

## 8  9 10 11 14 24

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have my laptop at hand to give your answer a try. I'll definitely do so later and report back.

Comment: Just tested the solution but I am not getting a set of results. It is giving me NULL as a result.  I am also getting a warning message: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL':

Comment: I have added the 2 functions before my 'foo' variable. I have then assigned the loop to a variable called final_list. I am getting a NULL as result when running 'sort(final_list)'. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: @user3115933 it should work. i made the complete answer

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to remove my line where I assigned the variable list2.